# Use Jenkins environment variable on remote server during job

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables

I have a Jenkins job (Freestyle) that executes commands on a remote server using SSH.  I would like to pass the JOB_NAME environment variable from Jenkins to the remote server for one of the commands.

For instance, on the remote server I would like to execute `mkdir ${JOB_NAME}`

I've tried every variation of the variable definition I can find, but always get an error `'JOB_NAME' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I've tried %JOB_NAME%, ${JOB_NAME}, ${env.JOB_NAME}, etc.

What's the appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're writing to a Windows share. The [Publish Over CIFS Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+CIFS+Plugin)

works nicely.